# Emacs 256 colors in iTerm2

Tags: bash, emacs, zsh, iterm2, spacemacs

I'm having some trouble getting 256 colors to work in Emacs (spacemacs).
I've now tried this is both native emacs and spacemacs but neither work.

My iTerm2 is running Build 3.1.20170419-nightly and is currently setup with xterm-256color and base16-ocean as theme.

Do not mind the `No theme file base16-default.dark.sh found`
It is a temporary error with the colortest script.

256 colors works perfectly in the GUI version which I guess means the theme is not broken.

[image: emacs M-x list-color-display]
[image: exports and settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is/was an issue with emacs-base16 and base16-shell compatibility.

Issue [opened](https://github.com/belak/base16-emacs/issues/12) on emacs-base16 GitHub

Solution:

```
(setq base16-theme-256-color-source "base16-shell")
```